# Ansible: parallel execution of delegate_to loop in one task

Tags: ansible

I use delegate_to with nested loop to distribute files among a group of hosts.

But in some cases there is a performance issue, since the task has to be finished on one host in order to be executed on the next one and so on.

In order to decrease the time needed for a task to be completed,is there a way to execute the delegate_to with loop in parallel?

```
- name: Create backup
  archive:
    path: xxxxx
    dest: xxxxx
    format: gz
  delegate_to: "{{hosts[ ( ((item[0] -1) + (item[1] | int)) - 1) % (hosts|length|int) ] }}"
  run_once: yes
  with_nested:
    - "{{loop_1}}"
    - "{{loop_2}}"
```

I have already tried the async module, but i realised that it's not the appropriate one for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `add_host` task to add your hosts into a in-memory group and create new play inside playbook.

An example:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Add hosts to in-memory group
      add_host:
        name: '{{hosts[ ( ((item.0 -1) + (item.1 | int)) - 1) % (hosts|length|int)
          ] }}'
        group: _backup_hosts
      loop: '{{ loop1 | product(loop2) | list }}'
- hosts: _backup_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: Create backup
      archive:
        path: xxxxx
        dest: xxxxx
        format: gz
      run_once: true
```